# How to model a flag stand?

Tags: modeling, transforms, workflow

I’m quite new to Blender and started to make some shapes. At the moment I was trying to make a flag shape like that:

[image: Flag]

But unfortunately, I’ve got no clue how to do it the proper way. If someone could give me a tip or redirect me to a video tutorial that would be very helpful!

Thanks!

[image: Current result]

Comment: Hello :). Where exactly are you having trouble? Do you want to model the logo from vertices or just a general shape of the flagpole? Please add an image of your result.

Comment: Hi Michal, the flagpole is not the issue. The hard thing for me is to transform the plane to a shape what looks like the image I posted above. I will take a screenshot of what I currently have 

Comment: Hey :). The flag shape is just two rectangles like this: https://i.imgur.com/8BlYaV9.gif

Answer (score 1):

Basically you do this steps:

1. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *-> Mesh ->  plane*
2. <kbd>7</kbd> -> Top Orthographic View
3. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> *-> Edit Mode*
4. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> *-> Turn snapping on*
5. Select the bottom vertices and <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> *-> subdivide*
6. Select the bottom left vertex
7. Press <kbd>G</kbd> -> <kbd>Y</kbd> -> Move down with mouse
8. Repeat step 6-7 for bottom right vertex

Here is a link to a video tutorial: https://youtu.be/3I-udSlXakM